# Facebook Marketing API (php SDK) 'invalid parameter' for AdCreative

Tags: php, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get the Marketing API examples work with PHP SDK. I've managed to create a Campaign, to set targeting, upload an image and create AdSet. However, I'm having trouble with the AdCreative and the Ad itself.

The code keeps breaking with 'Invalid Parameter', but I don't know which one is the invalid one. I've been debugging for 3 days now and I'm stuck. Here's the code I have:

Creates the Campaign:

```
$campaign = new Campaign(null, 'act_xxxxxxx');
$campaign->setData(array(
  CampaignFields::NAME => '#My Campaign#',
  CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE => CampaignObjectiveValues::LINK_CLICKS,
));

$campaign->create(array(
  Campaign::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Campaign::STATUS_PAUSED,
));
```

Create target audience:

```
$targeting = new Targeting();
$targeting->{TargetingFields::GEO_LOCATIONS} =
  array(
    'location_types' => array('recent'),
    'custom_locations' => array(
                            array(
                                'latitude'=> 'xx.xxxxxxx',
                                 'longitude'=> 'xx.xxxxxxx',
                                  'radius'=> 2,
                                   'distance_unit'=> 'kilometer')),
  );
```

Create Adset:

```
$start_time = (new \DateTime("+1 day"))->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$end_time = (new \DateTime("+2 day"))->format(DateTime::ISO8601);

$adset = new AdSet(null, 'act_xxxxxxxx');
$adset->setData(array(
  AdSetFields::NAME => '#My Adset#',
  AdSetFields::OPTIMIZATION_GOAL => AdSetOptimizationGoalValues::LINK_CLICKS,
  AdSetFields::BILLING_EVENT => AdSetBillingEventValues::LINK_CLICKS,
  AdSetFields::BID_AMOUNT => 2,
  AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET => 500,
  AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => $campaign->id,
  AdSetFields::TARGETING => $targeting,
  AdSetFields::START_TIME => $start_time,
  AdSetFields::END_TIME => $end_time,
));
$adset->create(array(
  AdSet::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => AdSet::STATUS_PAUSED,
));
```

Upload the image:

```
$image = new AdImage(null, 'act_xxxxxxxx');
$image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = 'fb-ad-images/xxxxx.jpeg';

$image->create();
$img_hash=$image->{AdImageFields::HASH}.PHP_EOL;
```

Creates the AdCreative:

```
$link_data = new AdCreativeLinkData();
$link_data->setData(array(
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::MESSAGE => 'try it out',
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::LINK => 'http://example.com',
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::CAPTION => 'My caption',
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::IMAGE_HASH => $img_hash,
));

$object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
$object_story_spec->setData(array(
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $link_data,
));

$creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_xxxxxxx');

$creative->setData(array(
  AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Sample Creative',
  AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
));

$creative->create();
```

Creates the Ad:

```
$data = array(
  AdFields::NAME => 'My Ad',
  AdFields::ADSET_ID => $adset->id,
  AdFields::CREATIVE => array(
    'creative_id' => $creative->id,
  ),
);

$ad = new Ad(null, 'act_xxxxxx');
$ad->setData($data);
$ad->create(array(
  Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED,
));
```

I've checked the validation compatibility of the parameters and all seems ok. The error is

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message 'Invalid parameter'`

Can anyone please help, I'm really stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion specifying the longititude and latitude wasn't a problem.
I recommend to check error message just directly from developer tool explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I prepared request with the same params and response was:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1885183,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode",
    "error_user_msg": "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad."
  }
}
```

So the reason was clear after it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you weren't specifying the longititude and latitude in the Targeting. The xx.xxx needs to be replaced with text. The way I figured that out is by enabling logging in the code and getting the actual API calls which indicated the error. Take a look at the updated code snippet.

```
<?php
$access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
$app_id = <APP_ID>;
$app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>';
// should begin with "act_" (eg: $account_id = 'act_1234567890';)
$account_id = 'act_<Ad_ACCOUNT_ID>';
// Configurations - End

if (is_null($access_token) || is_null($app_id) || is_null($app_secret)) {
  throw new \Exception(
    'You must set your access token, app id and app secret before executing'
  );
}

if (is_null($account_id)) {
  throw new \Exception(
    'You must set your account id before executing');
}

define('SDK_DIR', __DIR__ . '/..'); // Path to the SDK directory
$loader = include SDK_DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

// Create the CurlLogger
$logger = new CurlLogger();
// To write to a file pass in a file handler
// $logger = new CurlLogger(fopen('test','w'));
// Attach the logger to the Api instance
Api::instance()->setLogger($logger);

use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\CampaignObjectiveValues;
use FacebookAds\Object\Targeting;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\TargetingFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdSet;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\AdSetOptimizationGoalValues;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\AdSetBillingEventValues;

$campaign = new Campaign(null, $account_id);
$campaign->setData(array(
  CampaignFields::NAME => '#My Campaign#',
  CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE => CampaignObjectiveValues::LINK_CLICKS,
));

$campaign->create(array(
  Campaign::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Campaign::STATUS_PAUSED,
));

$targeting = new Targeting();
$targeting->{TargetingFields::GEO_LOCATIONS} =
  array(
    'location_types' => array('recent'),
    'custom_locations' => array(
                            array(
                                'latitude'=> '47.6062',
                                 'longitude'=> '122.3321',
                                  'radius'=> 2,
                                   'distance_unit'=> 'kilometer')),
  );

$start_time = (new \DateTime("+1 day"))->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$end_time = (new \DateTime("+2 day"))->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
echo $campaign->id."\n";
$adset = new AdSet(null, $account_id);
$adset->setData(array(
  AdSetFields::NAME => '#My Adset#',
  AdSetFields::OPTIMIZATION_GOAL => AdSetOptimizationGoalValues::IMPRESSIONS,
  AdSetFields::BILLING_EVENT => AdSetBillingEventValues::IMPRESSIONS,
  AdSetFields::BID_AMOUNT => 2,
  AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET => 500,
  AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => $campaign->id,
  AdSetFields::TARGETING => $targeting,
  AdSetFields::START_TIME => $start_time,
  AdSetFields::END_TIME => $end_time,
));
$adset->create(array(
  AdSet::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => AdSet::STATUS_PAUSED,
));
```